# Datepicker on a textbox in asp.net is not working

Tags: asp.net, textbox, datepicker

This is my JS for the datepicker.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#txtage").datepicker();
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my asp server side control.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtage" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

I want when user reach on this textbox then one calender should open from which they can select age and that date should display into this textbox.

Please tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems. Your ID doesn't match. You're using `txtage` in one place and `txtcity` in another. Is that a copy paste error?

If you're using nested templated controls (or a master page), your ID's on the client side are likely different than on the server side. You can change how the ID's on the client side are generated like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $("#txtage").datepicker();
        });
    });
</script>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtage" runat="server" ClientIdMode="static" /></td>
```

You also haven't shown your code for making sure jQuery and jQuery UI are loaded on the page.

Comment: it is a simple page i m creating just for learning purpose and that was really a copy paste error! But sir it is still not working.

Comment: @SachinYadav Did you make sure jQuery and jQuery UI are getting loaded? Did you check your browser console for errors?

Comment: Is the JQuery UI are compulsory added to this page?

Comment: Page is showing properly. but only this datepicker is not working

Comment: @SachinYadav I don't understand your last comment. It is not automatically added for you. And it is necessary to add jQuery UI if you're intending to use its [Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/).

Answer (score 1):

I just checked and this one works perfectly :

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="testDatePicker.Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="myTextBox"></asp:TextBox>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
$(function() {
    $("#myTextBox").datepicker();
});
```

I may advice you to remove the `ReadOnly` proprety since the datepicker will try to modify the textBox but not so sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `.ClientID` with the textbox id as follows.

**JS**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('#<%=txtage.ClientID%>').datepicker();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net takes a property that is `TextMode` That loads a calendar, which has to be equal `"Date"` - `TextMode="Date"`.

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtage" TextMode="Date" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>
```